# Why syntax of innerText and setItem is different in JS?

Tags: javascript

The syntax of `setItem` is like `setItem(key, value)` but the syntax of `innerText` is like `innerText= "text"`. Why `setItem` is not used like `setItem(key)=value`? is there any technical reason?

Comment: `setItem` is a method, `innerText` is a property. `.setItem(..)` is a method call, you can't assign anything to it. You can in fact do `localStorage.key = value` instead, but it's less safe (at least in theory). Lots of OO languages have the same distinction, and getter and setter methods are often implemented to prevent invalid values.

Comment: To clarify terminology, you are talking about JavaScript **syntax** here. The word "grammar" in this context is incorrect usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common ways that DOM (and other) APIs expose functionality. One of them is by using `=` to assign to a property:

```
someElm.textContent = 'foo';
someElm.onclick = () => console.log('clicked');
```

The other common method is by calling a function:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
someElm.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicked'));
```

That's just the way things are. Some developers find using one method or the other to be more convenient, compared to *only* having the option to use one of them.

Note that Storages *also* can be changed using `=`, without calling `setItem`. For example, the following two methods do the same thing:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('prop', 'val');
sessionStorage.prop = 'val';
```

The function-based method is very easy to understand - the object on which the method is called has that method as a property, and so can be invoked by passing the desired arguments.

The `=` based method is a bit weirder. What's happening underneath is the `=` is invoking a *setter*. You can see this if you examine the property descriptor:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, 'innerText'));
```

Here's an example of how to create such an API yourself:

```js
const obj = {
  set prop1(val) {
    console.log('prop1 setter invoked with', val);
  }
};
obj.prop1 = 'val1';

// Another example:
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop2', {
  set: (val) => {
    console.log('prop2 setter invoked with', val);
  }
});
obj.prop2 = 'val2';
```

Answer (score 0):

The technical reason is because of the differences between what we call `rvalue` and `lvalue`. An `rvalue` is an expression that can occur on the right side of an assignement `=` operator. Likewise, an `lvalue` can occur on the left side. In this case, a function call like `setItem(key)` is an `rvalue` and cannot occur on the left side of `=`.